# Javascript variable contains special character

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, special-characters

I have a Javascript with a variable containing special characters (I'm from DK and we are using three letters æøå). This is the result "fors�ger at skrive det s� langt s�" - so the special characters are replaced with �

The content is saved in a variable (b23) in the external javascript and inserted with the following function:

```
document.getElementById("rb-d3-3").innerHTML = b23;
```

Why is this wrong and what is the fix?

Maybe I should add that the site is running on a Wordpress

Thx

Comment: You're going to need to show how `b23` is created. If it's from PHP, like (`echo 'var b23 =" ' . $special . '";';`), you need to show that piece of code.

Comment: var b23 = "forsøger at skrive det så langt så";

Comment: So the variable is currently declared earlier in the sme javascript (I need to built som JSON lookup later where the variable will be set with data from mysql)

Comment: Most likely your file (whether it be .html or .js) is not saved with the encoding utf-8. Check your file encoding (in notepad++, under Encoding->Encode with utf-8 without BOM).

Comment: It is encoded correctly - so "Encode with utf-8 without BOM". Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you put the meta tag as well? If this doesn't work, you need to post your code (reproducible).

Comment: Can you post a link to the page? You can split the URL so it is not followed by Google spiders

Comment: is the var b23 set by ajax request ? in that case the ajax file must contain the correct header....

Comment: It works now!! As frustrating as it may be I cannot even tell you what made the trick. I must have worked with different versions... My apologies for disturbing with this question - I appreciate your input. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP script produces UTF-8 strings, don't forget to add the following meta in your HTML code:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime, depending on server default http header, you must convert your output.

If you are using php This:

```
echo utf8_encode($your_output);
```

Or you can try to convert :

```
echo iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $your_output);
```